How can I use `std::array::try_from_fn` on stable compiler?
I'm writing some code where I could really do with a function which is able to create an array from a function/iterator in a fallible way.
I don't care about catching all the errors just whether or not an error occurs. Therefore I could really use something like std::array::try_from_fn. However, it's currently in nightly rust so I can't use it in this project.
Is it possible to implement a similar function on stable rust?
Thanks

The reason this function is unstable is because it uses nightly only trait Try, which abstracts over failibility. But if you only care for functions that return Result (thus can fail only with some error), then you could write such function pretty easy yourself.

The reason why std::array::try_from_fn and other similar functions are unstable, is that they use unstable trait Try. This trait will allow your code to be generic over "fallibility", but currently there is no consensus on how it should be defined, and so it (and all functions that use it) is unstable.
However if you don't need this generalisation, and only want to support functions returning Result<T, E>, you can write a version of try_array_from_fn yourself. Here is example implementation:
use std::mem::{self, MaybeUninit};

/// Guard that holds invariant that first self.initialised
/// elements of self.data are initialised and will drop them.
struct Guard<'data, T, const N: usize> {
    data: &'data mut [MaybeUninit<T>; N],
    initialised: usize,
}

impl<T, const N: usize> Drop for Guard<'_, T, N> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        for i in 0..self.initialised {
            // SAFETY: elemnts from 0 up to self.intialised were initialised.
            unsafe {
                self.data[i].assume_init_drop();
            }
        }
    }
}

pub fn try_array_from_fn<F, T, E, const N: usize>(mut f: F) -> Result<[T; N], E>
where
    F: FnMut(usize) -> Result<T, E>,
{
    // SAFETY: Elements of array are MaybeUninit<T>, so it is safe to call
    // .assume_init() on uninitialised memory.
    //
    // This is manual implementation of unstable method MaybeUninit::uninit_array.
    let mut data: [MaybeUninit<T>; N] = unsafe { MaybeUninit::uninit().assume_init() };
    let mut guard = Guard {
        data: &mut data,
        initialised: 0,
    };

    for i in 0..N {
        // When current ? operator will make this function return,
        // guard's Drop will be called and previously initialised
        // elements will be dropped.
        let elem = f(i)?;
        guard.data[i].write(elem);
        guard.initialised += 1;
    }

    // All data was initialised, so we forget guard to prevent it
    // from dropping data.
    mem::forget(guard);

    // SAFETY: all elements were initialised and MaybeUninit<T> has the same
    // layout as T.
    //
    // transmute_copy is used instead of transmute,
    // because transmute cannot realise that size of [MaybeUninit<T>; N]
    // is the same as the size of [T; N].
    //
    // This is manual implementation of unstable method MaybeUninit::array_assume_init.
    unsafe { Ok(mem::transmute_copy(&data)) }
}


That's not true. E.g. Iterator::try_for_each() is stable.
